# How to wait until Kafka container is started

Tags: testcontainers

I am using https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/ and would like configure the container, so that before my test get started, make sure Kafka is up and running.

How to archive it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testcontainers already has built-in waits for readiness:
https://www.testcontainers.org/features/startup_and_waits/

`KafkaContainer` waits until it is listening on Kafka's port (and ZooKeeper's port, if you use the build-in one), it won't start otherwise.